# Coral TPU on Raspberry Compute Module 4

Tags: pcb-design

I'm researching on Coral TPU on Carrier Board for Compute Module 4 implementation. I have made contact with Google about this implementation but they told to me that Coral won't be able to work on a carrier PCB, but then I have seen this:

https://www.gumstix.com/manufacturer/cm4-poe-smart-camera.html

https://www.gumstix.com/manufacturer/cm4-pixhawk-fmuv6.html

and now I don't know if it will work or not. I'm new on design and components and I don't understand what is going here. Will it work or not?

Thank you so much.

EDIT: A little misunderstood with Google. I asked them if I can put Coral on a carrier board for CM4 using a PCIe-USB 3.0 Controller. They said to me that that design didn't work correctly. I asked to Google about Gumstix boards and they say that that design is fine and if i want to do something like gumstix i have to use PCIe to USB 3.0 controller, and put Coral near to the controller ( (is the same that I want to try but i think they didn't understand me). It should work fine.

Comment: the usb accelerator works with raspberry pi so something is possible.

Comment: Yes, and there are some designs with the chip on other PCB, different to the SoC PCB, but they said that these designs don't work.

Comment: what did they say, in verbatim?

Comment: @MarcusMüller We are talking about SoCs like RPi CM4 and other CPU SoCs.  Using a carrier board for the Coral Accelerator module for the CM4 SoC will not work, as the extra connector will break the signal to the PHY trace. The only way to make the USB3 interface work is to solder the CM4 and Acceleration right next to each other on the same PCB to keep the PHY trace as short as possible.  

Also, CM4's PCIe bus implementation has not used the latest standard and lacks the support for MSI-X interrupt for PCIe, so the PCIe interface between the CM4 and Accelerator module does not work..

Comment: Solved, when I asked to Google about Gumstix designs they told to me that they are fine (in the beginning I asked for the same distribuition, pcie to usb 3.0 controller, but I think they didn't understand me).

Comment: hm, USB3 over connectors does work – the M.2 connector is an example of that. However, I don't know anything about the CM4's connector design, so there might be enough mismatch/losses so that any additional length kills USB3. Anyways, typically PCIe is about as robust as USB3 (if USB3 isn't even more robust, being an external bus by design), so this is a bit surprising.